# Какой нужен уровень знания Java, чтобы перейти к разработке Android-приложений?

Tags: java, android

Какие именно разделы Java задействованы в разработке приложений под андроид?

Comment: Java Se. Можете прочитать книгу Философия Java. Не просто прочитать ну и начать понимать код.  И после можно переходить к Android разработке.

Comment: java core изучить можно по урокам на ютубе

Comment: ну, мне удобней по лекциям и учебнику, но мне интересно, что еще используется, кроме java core

Comment: После javacore изучение андроид программирования на java логично же. Создание view, адаптеры, и прочее прочее прочее

Comment: в андроид только java core (непосредствено язык программирования). Андроид имеет свой фреймворк (собственно Android API) для взаимодействия с системой, экраном и прочей переферией

Comment: лично я начал писать на андроид зная только Qbasic ) а что? операторы для циклов , для условий даже в синтаксисе практически не отличаются. Да и вообще синтаксис java был интуитивно понятен, поэтому прочитав 30 проц книги Шилдта "Руководство для начинающих" я понял что можно переходит к урокам по андроид. Но это не лучший подход. Вам java core с головой хватит! Ну и ООП конечно же понимать вместе с принципами SOLID. Кстати уроки Немчинского на ютубе по ООП шикарны

Comment: Следует изучить устройство и `API`. без этих знаний нет смысла от знаний `Java`.

Answer (score 2):

**Java SE (Standard Edition)**:

- [Базовый синтаксис](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y11uOcbJxgQ)
- [ООП](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNOUCixREmM&index=3&list=PLlb7e2G7aSpQith1Z6xRpU8jFPgkh_Gvz)
- [Коллекции](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taRtTtMRPzs)
- [Лямбды](https://habr.com/post/224593/) и [ссылки на методы](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-ssylki-na-metody/)
- [Stream API](https://annimon.com/article/2778)
- [Многопоточность](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/8.1.php)
- [Fork / Join Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0dGLFtRR9c)
- [Пакет java.io](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html)
- [Пакет java.lang](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html)
- [Пакет java.net](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html)
- Прочие классы из [пакета java.util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)
- [JavaFX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=db2wxZ1yDl8&list=PLwwk4BHih4fi1rkT7XAHrwya3Qjuo63AK), но это уже дело вкуса

**Сторонние**:

- Уметь работать с [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) или ему подобными.
- [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/overview-summary.html) (не обязательно пригодится, но нужно знать)

Также пригодится знание XML и понимать различия между Android и других ОС. И в принципе понимать, что такое Android.

Еще нужно знание английского языка на среднем уровне.

P.S. это информация лично на мой взгляд.